# Error Provider for a DateTimePicker and a Textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox, int, datetimepicker

I am running an application in Windows forms where I make records, but validate that some fields are filled in. I am using Error Provider, however, when I cause the error they mark me all except the DateTimePicker and a Textbox where I must enter Int what error my code can have ?

```
private void btnCargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   // Method to clear the error provider (if they had already appeared before)
    LimpiarErrorICono();
    if (txtSalesOrderI.Text == string.Empty || txtModelo.Text == string.Empty || txtCustomer.Text == string.Empty || txtTotalI.Text == string.Empty || cmbPriorityI.Text == string.Empty
        || cmbPriorityStatus.Text == string.Empty || dtmpDateReceived.Checked)  
    {
        this.MensajeError("Faltan Ingresar Datos");

        if (txtSalesOrderI.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            ErrorIcono.SetError(txtSalesOrderI, "Ingrese un SalesOrder");
        }

        if (txtCustomer.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            ErrorIcono.SetError(txtCustomer, "Ingrese un Customer");
        }

        if(txtModelo.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            ErrorIcono.SetError(txtModelo, "Ingrese un Modelo");
        }


          // In this field it is the text box that an int must go and I don't see 
            the error provider when I don't enter anything
        if(txtTotalI.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            ErrorIcono.SetError(txtTotalI, "Ingrese un Numero");
        }

        if(cmbPriorityI.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            ErrorIcono.SetError(cmbPriorityI, "Ingrese una Prioridad");
        }

        if (cmbPriorityStatus.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            ErrorIcono.SetError(cmbPriorityStatus, "Ingrese una Estatus");
        }


        // DateTimePicker in which I must check a date and if the error should not appear icon
        if (dtmpDateReceived.Checked == false)
        {
            ErrorIcono.SetError(dtmpDateReceived, "Ingrese una Fecha");
        }

    }
```

Comment: 1) The first looong `if` checks is not necessary because you are checking the same thing ahead. 2) To clear the `ErrorProvider` just do `MensajeError.Clear();` in the first line. 3) check the `TextBox-es` like: `if (txtTotalI.Text.Trim() == string.Empty) { .. }` or `if (txtTotalI.TextLength == 0) { }` 4) As for the `DateTimePicker` your code won't check it since in the first long `ifs` check you have `|| dtmpDateReceived.Checked`. So get rid of the long `ifs` check.

Answer (score 0):

Use else if statement it will go to check step by step

Or loop over all TextBoxes and check ALL

```
Foreach(TextBox txt in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
 if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txt.Text))
{
 errorprovider1.SetError(txt, "Empty Field");
}
}
```